# Group data calculation per two columns in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I would like to get the total number of wins, the total number of matches he played and the ration of the wins/matches per player per year from the following table data.

```
+---------+---------+--------+--------+--------+------+
| player1 | player2 | score1 | score2 | winner | year |
+---------+---------+--------+--------+--------+------+
|  100000 |  100125 |      4 |      0 | 100000 | 2016 |
|  100125 |  100126 |      4 |      0 | 100125 | 2016 |
|  100130 |  100000 |      0 |      4 | 100000 | 2017 |
|  100125 |  100130 |      4 |      0 | 100125 | 2017 |
+---------+---------+--------+--------+--------+------+
```

So the asked query should normally return rows like this:

```
+--------+---------------+------+-------+------+
| player | total_matches | wins | ratio | year |
+--------+---------------+------+-------+------+
| 100000 |             1 |    1 | 1     | 2016 |
| 100000 |             1 |    1 | 1     | 2017 |
| 100125 |             2 |    1 | 0.5   | 2016 |
| 100125 |             1 |    1 | 1     | 2017 |
| 100126 |             1 |    0 | 0     | 2016 |
| 100130 |             2 |    0 | 0     | 2017 |
+--------+---------------+------+-------+------+
```

If I group by winner and year I can get easily the wins per year but then I cannot get the total_matches and the ratio.
Is there any other way to do this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT player, 
       COUNT(*) AS total_matches, 
       SUM(player = winner) AS wins,
       SUM(player = winner) / COUNT(*) AS ratio,
       `year`
FROM (
   SELECT player1 AS player, winner, `year`
   FROM mytable

   UNION ALL 

   SELECT player2, winner, `year`
   FROM mytable) AS t
GROUP BY player, `year`
```

The query uses `UNION ALL` in order to get one table that contains all `player1`, `player2` values in a single column. It also uses *conditional aggregation* in order to calculate the `wins` field: `SUM(player = winner)` will sum only those records having `player = winner`.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/313de/1)

Comment: Thanks Giorgos. This query did it! Only one concern because the table of course contains much more rows (about 1M) is there any delay possibility because of the UNION ALL?

Comment: @dimoss You can try the query with your actual data and see how it performs. Given the table structure I cannot think of any alternative to using a `UNION`.

Comment: I will try it in my actual data. Thanks again!